# Trying to do this but with no success. P'se help me with this Little issue

Tags: c#, linq

Guys come on I know this might seem a walk over for all of you but I have failed to achieve what I intend to. my linq query

```
  XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"E:\OBJECT ORIENTED DEV'T\file.xml");
    XElement root = doc.Root;


    var items = from item in doc.Descendants("ModuleSchedule")
                                          .Descendants("ModuleTimeTable")

                where item.Attribute("Module_ID").Value.Equals("001")
                select new
                {


                   ModuleId = item.Attribute("Module_ID").Value, //works fine

                   Slots = item.Attribute("Day").Value  //Not sure how to achieve this
                   Slots = item.Attribute("Time").Value  // Not sure how to achieve   this

                };



    GridView1.DataSource = items;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

And Here is my XML structure

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ModuleSchedule>
 <ModuleTimeTable Module_ID="001" ModuleName="Module Name 1">
  <Slot Day="Monday" Time="09:30"/>
  <Slot Day="Tuesday" Time="14:30"/>
  <Slot Day="Fridayday" Time="09:30"/>
  <Slot Day="Saturday" Time="12:30"/>
 </ModuleTimeTable>
<ModuleTimeTable Module_ID="002" ModuleName="Module Name 2">
  <Slot Day="Monday" Time="09:30"/>
  <Slot Day="Tuesday" Time="14:30"/>
  <Slot Day="Fridayday" Time="09:30"/>
  <Slot Day="Saturday" Time="12:30"/>
 </ModuleTimeTable>
<ModuleTimeTable Module_ID="003" ModuleName="Module Name 3">
  <Slot Day="Monday" Time="09:30"/>
  <Slot Day="Tuesday" Time="14:30"/>
  <Slot Day="Fridayday" Time="09:30"/>
  <Slot Day="Saturday" Time="12:30"/>    
</ModuleTimeTable>
```

I would like to retrieve all slots associated with the module Id, put them in a gridview table like day and time.

Thank you

Comment: Could someone p'se helpe me with returning all slots where Module_ID is for example "003". The suggested solution below works but at the moment It returns only the last slot. Thank you once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
 doc.Descendants("ModuleSchedule")
    .Descendants("ModuleTimeTable")
```

Just use  `doc.Descendants("ModuleTimeTable")` or `doc.Root.Elements("ModuleTimeTable")`

Also you might want to use *explicit cast* when getting the value of an attribute or element in order to avoid possible exceptions:

```
var items = from item in doc.Descendants("ModuleTimeTable")
            where (string)item.Attribute("Module_ID") == "001"
            select new
            {
                ModuleId = (int) item.Attribute("Module_ID"),
                Day = (string) item.Element("Slot").Attribute("Day"),
                Time = (string) item.Element("Slot").Attribute("Time")
            };
```

Comment: Just a small question p'se if you dont mind, at the moment it only takes the last slot. How would I put a loop in the query to be able to get all slots?

Comment: would you be able to help me if at all you can with this one. "[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22912493/gridview-with-a-dropdownlist-to-xml-file)"